# Image View Fill Empty Space ViewPager Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I've Been Following this tutorial [Image Slide Using View Pager](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/) but i cant make  the image View inside view pager fill the complete space inside view pager both horizontally and vertically. Any idea how to do this?

I've tried this one in my Page adapter

```
mImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

but still no luck :(

my Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="2dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/img_slideshow_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img_border" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/img_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/indicator"
        android:background="#88343434"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ededed" />

    <apps.modisku.com.modisku.helper.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_pager"
        android:padding="10dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="3dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/txt_image_slider" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

My PageAdapter

```
public class ImageSlideAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoadingListener imageListener;
    FragmentActivity activity;
    List<Product> products;
    HomeFragment homeFragment;

    public ImageSlideAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, List<Product> products,
                             HomeFragment homeFragment) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.homeFragment = homeFragment;
        this.products = products;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loadingicontransprant).build();

        imageListener = new ImageDisplayListener();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vp_image, container, false);

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.image_display);


       // mImageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mScreenWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                Fragment fragment = null;
                Log.d("position adapter", "" + position);
                Product product = (Product) products.get(position);
                arguments.putParcelable("singleProduct", product);

                // Start a new fragment
                fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = activity
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.promofragment, fragment,
                        ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                transaction.addToBackStack(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        imageLoader.displayImage(
                ((Product) products.get(position)).getImageURL(), mImageView,
                options, imageListener);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    private static class ImageDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections
                .synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                                      Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                 }
               }
           }
        }
    }
```

[image: My Apps Screenshoot]

Comment: what there is there inside your viewpager ? is it fragment or simple view ? can you please share your adapter code also

Comment: can you please tell if below solution is working for you ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Use FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/txt_image_slider" />

       </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: If this is your, xml which will be in fragments ?

Comment: hey can you please share your adapter code also, I would like to play around with this. seems interesting problem to me

Comment: hey try now, actually there was padding of 3 DP. I have removed it, now image will come all over screen I am sure !

Comment: Why are you using pagerAdapter why not FragmentPagerAdapter ?

Comment: And also try with  mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FITXY);

Comment: Its Work Now :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with it ..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="3dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/txt_image_slider" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will be useful for you.